# Prove $e^x$ is its own derivative via power series?

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

$$ \frac{d}{dx}e^x =\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$
This isn't as straightforward as I thought it would be. I'm assuming there is some way to shift indices to complete the proof, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: You have a couple of equals signs missing.

Comment: I don't think so, the second and third expressions are just simplifications, I'm not changing any equivalence.

Comment: The equals sign is a verb, and without verbs you have no sentences.

Comment: But if you understand the problem so well that you know exactly where the equal signs should go, that proves adding them is superfluous.

Comment: "But if you understand the problem so well that you know exactly where the equal signs should go, that proves adding them is superfluous." Uh, no. If you write nonsense the fact that one might guess what you mean doesn't make it ok to write nonsense. Very curious attitude, btw - one would hope that you're interested in learning to write mathematiics correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, careful with your first term, since you are dividing by $(-1)!$. The first term is constant and differentiates to $0$, so your sum should start from $n = 1$.

Then, just make a substitution $m = n - 1$. When $n = 1$, we get $m = 0$, and so

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} e^x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m!}.$$

Comment: But where in the differentiation process is the summation forced to jump an index? Otherwise I don't see the index shift you've made.

Comment: When you differentiate the first term (i.e. the constant $1 = x^0 / 0!$), the result is not $x^{-1} / (-1)!$, but $0$. I would agree with the alternate form $ 0 \cdot x^{-1} / 0!$, but you cannot cancel $0 / 0!$ to $1 / (-1)!$, as the latter is meaningless.

Comment: As for the substitution, I'm just writing out the same terms, using an index $m$ instead. When $m = 0$, the term of $\sum \frac{x^m}{m!}$ is the same as the term of $\sum \frac{x^{n - 1}}{(n - 1)!}$ when $n = 1$. Similarly, subbing in $m = 1$ will produce the same term as $n = 2$, etc. The same terms are being summed, so the series are identical!

Comment: Okay, well my biggest concern was the 1/x term but if you keep it with the rest of the first term, then it goes to 0, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the infinite sum as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
Then 
$$\frac{d}{dx} (1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me people are giving correct versions of the calculation, hence showing that your conclusion is wrong, but without pinning down exactly where the error in your version is.  The error is here:  The "identity" $$\frac k{k!}=\frac1{(k-1)!}$$is not true if $k=0$. (You obtain that identity by cancelling a $k$ in the numerator and denominator. Ignoring the fact that if $k=0$ there *is* no factor of $k$ in $k!$, in general you cannot "cancel" zeroes: $1(0)=2(0)$, hence $1=2$.)